# Can you shoot down Pharah's rockets?

Tags: overwatch

Can you shoot Pharah's rockets (or any other projectiles) out of the sky? Destroying slow-moving projectiles before they reach you is a staple in many shooting games, so I'm wondering if you can do it in Overwatch. I don't think I've ever seen it happen, but I haven't explicitly tried it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't. The only entity you can destroy (with normal damage) before it detonates is Junkrat's RIP-Tire. D.Va's Defense Matrix is the closest thing to what you're thinking of, but normal weapons can't do that.

Comment: Not sure what the defense matrix has to do with it?

Comment: @DCShannon When using Defense Matrix, D.Va is manually shooting down projectiles and bullets that enter the cone with the distance markers.

Comment: Really? I have like 8 hours of D.Va playtime and I never noticed that. Just seemed like a shield. I'll look for that.

Comment: @DCShannon Pay close attention to what happens to the projectiles. D.Va fires lasers to vaporize them, which also means an enemy inside the cone won't be able to shoot out of it either. As soon as they try to shoot, D.Va will disintegrate the bullet just as it leaves their weapon.

Comment: You can also shoot Junkrat's mine before it lands. Not sure about his trap. Same for Widowmaker's trap

Comment: D.Va's defense matrix works on anything that is not a channeled ability. This means it works on all Junkrat's mine+trap, Widow's mine, Tracer's bomb and even Zarya's ultimate (it's a projectile before it lands). It will not block abilities like Mei's freeze ray, Zarya's primary or secondary attacks (primary is channeled, and secondary is classed as an energy attack) or Zenyatta's Orb of Discord.

On that note: I need to test if it can absorb the attacks from Winston's ultimate...

Comment: Looks like you can [destroy Junkrat's Concussion Mine in midair](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4oc1yy/i_killed_a_junkrat_mine_midair_with_a_soldier/).

Comment: @KizTrap I love playing Mei and watching D.Vas try to DM my freeze spray instead of GTFOing :)

Comment: @KizTrap For reference - defense matrix *does* negate Zarya's secondary attack. I think I've also seen Junkrat traps (not the mine, the bear trap thingy) get through, but I'm not quite as sure about that one.

Comment: @MageXy I wrote that comment a while back, I think it got changed pre-Season 2 and I forgot to come back and edit. The trap isn't a projectile, which would explain why Defense Matrix may not catch it. Thanks for clarifying though :)